# Learning to develop Flash content

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-builder

My son, aged 10 wants to learn how to build flash content. Starting with some simple animations and eventually  on to games.

Are the any free/express tools available for this sort of thing or is the only option an expensive software package from adobe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your son is into development then you can use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) ( a windows only IDE ) to develop your flash content in pure AS3. Adobe make available the [FlexSDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK) for free which has the required compiler that the IDE requires to compile.

If he wants to use the timeline, then personally I know of nothing free.

Comment: @Fly_Trap, FYI, FlashDevelop comes bundled with the FlexSDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the free trial of Flash CS5, and try it out for a month. You could certainly get your feet wet in that time.  If he really likes it, you can get the Student and Teacher version of Adobe Flash CS5 for $169.99 (amazon), since I'm guessing he is a student. It's still expensive, but nowhere near the full commercial version, and they are identical, and can be used for commercial purposes.

That being said, FlashDevelop is my IDE of choice for Actionscript (Flash's scripting language). It is possible to build flash projects entirely in FlashDevelop without spending a penny.  And there are so many tutorials out there for pure Actionscript projects, if you can't buy Flash, this is the way to go.